# boost.python argument type mismatch (numpy.int64 -> int)

Tags: python, numpy, boost-python

I'm running into this problem:

```
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Dirichlet.Observe(int, numpy.int64, float)
did not match C++ signature:
    Observe(unsigned int, unsigned int, double)
```

Seems close enough?

After doing some replacement, it seems that the middle argument is the problem.  How do I convert numpy.int64 to int?

Comment: An int64 is nowhere near an unsigned int. It's kind of like trying to pack an int into a byte.

Comment: @anon, surely, it could truncate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could you try...

```
int(numpyint)
```

Comment: Ha, I just had to do `int(...)`.  I'm still new to python.

Comment: @spenthil, thanks.  I expected numpy.int64 to implicitly cast to int.  I wonder why it doesn't.

Comment: @neil-g, http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/YJlerGqGfmQKA62zIaRY explains why (I think).