# How to get a pandas dataframe to a .tde?

Tags: python, pandas, extract, tableau-api

I'm working with a Pandas dataframe.

I have all of my data loaded and all of the manipulations I would like to perform, done.

I'm looking for the specific lines of code which can take this dataframe and copy the rows to a table which I have defined as part of a .tde extract.

If anyone has experience with this I'd love to see what you wrote. There are examples online for using a .csvreader with python which loops through the rows and adds them as they are being read but I can't find any example of how to take data stored in a dataframe and apply it to a table defined as part of an extract.

EDIT: So at the moment I'm trying to loop through each column, row by row and add each specific cell. For some reason I get thrown this error.

```
colnames = all_data.columns

for r in range(0, len(all_data)):
newrow = tde.Row(tableDef)
for c in range(0, len(colnames)):
    if str(colnames[c]) == 'Run Date':
        newrow.setCharString(c, all_data.iloc[r,c])
    elif str(colnames[c]) == 'Sales Order':
        newrow.setCharString(c, all_data.iloc[r,c])  
    else:
        newrow.setNull(c)

table.insert(newrow)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-db8a798ec66b> in <module>()
      5             newrow.setCharString(c, all_data.iloc[r,c])
      6         elif str(colnames[c]) == 'Sales Order':
----> 7             newrow.setCharString(c, all_data.iloc[r,c])
      8         else:
      9             newrow.setNull(c)

    C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dataextract\Base.pyc in setCharString(self, columnNumber, value)
    335             self._handle
    336           , c_int(columnNumber)
--> 337           , c_char_p(value)
    338         )
    339 

TypeError: string or integer address expected instead of numpy.int64 instance
```

Answer (score 2):

Tableau provides an API for creating data extract (TDE) files - [DETAILS](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v8.0/pro/online/en-us/extracting_TDE_API.html) and [DOWNLOAD](http://www.tableau.com/data-extract-api)

With the Python drivers for the API, you can easily convert a dataframe.

See, for example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26126868/2327328) in how to turn your data into the TDE format

Comment: I've read all the documentation I'm just not sure how to apply it. There is no clear instruction as to moving data from a dataframe to a virtual table in python and I know this is a problem for other people using different type of target table (https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/68). when I try to insert the dataframe to the table as shown in the tutorials, an error returns: "dataframe not callable"

Comment: Please edit your question to include code samples of what you are trying, and the traceback of any errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your traceback, the problem is that you are trying to insert a numpy.int64 instead of a "regular" integer.

For example, to convert to a regular integer before inserting, use the int() function:

```
int(numpyint)
```

Other datatypes will also need to be converted, so use the str(), unicode() or float() functions.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383515/boost-python-argument-type-mismatch-numpy-int64-int/4384011#4384011)